# Trying to add a folder structure and eclipse projects to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, repository

It's funny, I've been working with SVN (Tortoise on Windows)  for a relatively long time, but I've never used other actions than checkout, commit and merge since the projects I worked on already existed.
Now I want to put an Eclipse project under version control by my own and realize that I am too stupid to do that. There is already a new SVN server with emtpy branches/tags/trunk folders, it was created by another person.

1.)

My intention is to add three subfolders to the trunk folder - these three folders are just for a better structure, they should not have anything to to with version control or my eclipse project (apart from the fact that I want to put my Eclipse project in one of those three folders in the second step).
But how can I do that? I created those three folders on my hard drive via Windows Explorer and tried to put them in the SVN's trunk folder by using the import function of Tortoise. This failed with the following log message:

```
Command: Import C:\New Folder to https://<SVN-Adress>/trunk
Adding C:\New Folder\folderA
Adding C:\New Folder\folderB
Adding C:\New Folder\folderC
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook
svn: URL file '<SVN-Adress>/trunk/folderA' non-existent in that revision
svn: URL file '<SVN-Adress>/trunk/folderB' non-existent in that revision
svn: URL file '<SVN-Adress>/trunk/folderC' non-existent in that revision
```

2.)

In the second step, I want to add my eclipse project to folderA and another eclipse project to folderB. Since there is already content in the eclise project folders, the "Create Repository here" command of Tortoise SVN doesn't seem the way to go. Apart from the question how to do that properly, is there something to be aware of? E.g. are the two eclipse projects independet and isolated later on or does a commit of the one project also increase the version of the other project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `https://<SVN-Adress>/trunk` to your root folder (`c:\New Folder`), then SVN-add all the files and folders you want to be in source control, and commit.